# How to represent a Calendar date in a json object using springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, calendar

I have this following json object:

```
{
"username":"test",
"customerName":"test",
"accessReasons":"tes",
"leaseHours":"8"
}
```

This represents the time a certain user has to do a certain task (which is the sysdate + the leaseHours)

On my controller, I create an object with the information that I receive in that json:

```
thatObject obj=new thatObject (jsonObjectFromPostBody)
```

By doing that, an instance of thatObject is created this way:

```
public thatObject(thatObject aci) {
    this.username=aci.getUsername();
    this.customerName=aci.getCustomerName();
    this.accessReasons=aci.getAccessReasons();
    this.beginDate= new GregorianCalendar();
    long sum=beginDate.getTimeInMillis()+aci.getLeaseHours().getTimeInMillis();
    this.endDate=(Calendar)beginDate.clone();
    this.endDate.setTimeInMillis(sum);
}
```

As you can see, my endDate is the enitial date + the time that the user has permissions to be active(which in this case is 8 hours)

But my problem is that I am using calendar and I cant represent those 8 hours on my json object, so when Im calculating the endTime it will be 0, how can I represent those 8 hours on my json or sum those 8 hours to my beginDate variable?

Comment: Do not use `Calendar` (nor `GregorianCalendar`). Absolutely not. It's an obsolete class that takes ages to instantiate and has serious issues. Use the appropriate object from `java.time` (depending on whether you use local dates or zone/offset dates). You can easily add periods of time to those objects.

Comment: okay it is really confusing, what is the type of  `endDate` and `beginDate` in POJO? and what do you want to set to them, it will be helpful if you can show some input and output

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change the type of *leaseHours* property to *Integer* in *thatObject*?
In that case you can do something like this:

```
long sum=beginDate.getTimeInMillis() + aci * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```